# Arc sign between letters

Tags: symbols, linguistics, tipa

I need to use an top arc sign between two letters, for example:

A ͡ B

I have been looking it up on the Internet, but in all the solutions I have found (e.g., package `arcs`, `tipa`'s `\texttoptiebar`) the arc appears on the bottom:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You're possibly using `\texttoptiebar` in a wrong way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\texttoptiebar{AB} \texttoptiebar{xy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried with: `\texttoptiebar{ }`, and that was the output. I would need the arc to be higher.

Comment: If you need the tie over a blank space, use `\texrtoptiebar{\phantom{A}}`

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because it is an ordinary text, tie accent should be enough:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\t AB

\t ii
\end{document}
```

[image]